# c# How can i use one of all network adapters for sending UDP message

Tags: c#, udpclient

I have PC with more network adapter and I using UdpClient class.I dont know how I can determinate which adapter must be using for sending method.
I wanna send broadcast from all my adapters gradually.Or just from one specific adapter.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify network adapters, but you can specify the source IP address. Typically each network adapter will have one or more IP addresses so that way you can indirectly specify network adapters.

To use a specific source IP address, use the [`UdpClient(IpEndPoint)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k227d11f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor.

Comment: In constructor can i define on which adapter can I only listen(or not???).But i need to tell which adapter want I use to sending.Because I need try to send broadcast from all my adapters.I need someone like scanner of server. –